# Retrieve StripeView values on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, stripe-payments, xamarin.forms

I'm currently integrating Stripe API on Xamarin.Forms and what I have is I can generate the card token but only through putting the card values as parameters:

```
var token = await DependencyService.Get<IStripe> ().CreateToken ("4242424242424242", "123", 16, 12);
```

Now, I am using the StripeView as the UI but how can I retrieve the values I've entered to put them as replacement on the parameters? Thanks!

Currently referencing from this post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49499/stripeview-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

StripeView that you use in Xamarin Forms has the properties

Number
Guid
CVC
Name
ExpiryYear
ExpiryMonth

Get the values directly from this control.

Comment: Okay, I'll try those, Adam. Thanks!